# In which case a request referer can be a domain different than the page origin?

Tags: html, httprequest, http-referer

Example of a page on `https://test.com/abc/`

User clicks on a link with `href="https://testtarget.com/"`

In rare cases, the server received `https://testtarget.com` as referer instead of `https://test.com`

It happens for multiple users, all have recent Chrome versions.

What could be the reason?

** UPDATE **

Do you know popular privacy software/add-on that would change the referrer to the request domain?

Comment: You're probably seeing the referrer from the HTTP->HTTPS redirection, rather than the original navigation to the HTTP URL. You should capture a network trace to see precisely what's going on.

Comment: You might also have `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`, which would prevent the referrer being sent, since you're navigating from HTTPS to HTTP. [Referrer-Policy - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean to use unsecure http link, it's a typo. I updated the example.

Comment: It still sounds like a redirection on the target site to me. As I said, try capturing a network trace of the navigation to see what requests are made and what headers are sent.

Comment: Access log confirm referrer is testtarget.com and response status 302. There was no prior call with a 200 response.